# Redis locks for cluster mode enabled

Tags: database, redis, locking, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I have read how redis standalone provides optimistic locking. I have also come across Redlock algorithm on redis website which is available for distributed locking.

Now what I don't understand is why do we need distributed locking (cluster mode enabled) in Redis.

In distributed mode enabled, we can have up to 15 shards, each shard having non - overlapping records. Since there is no shared data, what is the need for distributed locks?

Won't optimistic locking for each shared do the trick? One reason might be multi-key operations but other than that I can't think of anything.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Distributed locks in redis are usually used for locking a distributed app, not specifically data in redis. For example - a shopping app has a "pay" button, and processing the transaction might take a few seconds, during which the user might hit the button multiple times.

Each of those REST calls might go to a different web server. How do you reliably prevent multiple billings? With a redis lock, of course!

But If you use a single node/shard lock, you risk this node failing at this exact time window, resulting in botched or duplicate transactions. Using a distributed lock a-la RedLock algorithm, makes sure that even a single node's failure will keep the lock in a consistent state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As per my understanding redis is single threaded so even if it gets requests from different web servers the database will first complete one transaction before moving on to the other. How does locking help. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You lock the application as a whole, not redis itself.